Two tower recommender system
I am exploring two tower architecture for user and content recommendation. The data that I have, solely consists of positive user and content interactions. (i.e. I do not have any data for scenarios when an user ignored the content that was presented).
I am struggling with the following implementation details.

In-batch negative sampling seems a popular method for training the candidate generation phase. In a batch an user Ui and content Cj is treated as a negative sample if 'i' is not equal to 'j'. But if a batch has multiple interaction records for a specific user, in-batch negative sampling could lead to conflicting training data for the model. How do we handle the issue? Do we need to ensure that each batch has only a single interaction record for a given user?

If I want to measure the model performance in the validation set (or want to use early stopping), how do I generate negative samples for the validation set. I can use the same methodology as in-batch sampling. But I will run into the same problem of multiple interactions for a given user.

Could you please recommend a good way to split the data into training and validation set? Should I ensure that I have a set of users and all their interactions only in the validation set. i.e. for those users there are no interactions in the training set


Any inputs and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
